# Container for precompiled GUI Blocks

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, design-patterns

so here's my problem. I have a (large and growing) set of single-window applications written in C++ with a QT GUI. Basically each of these programs is used to connect with a different hardware device and consists of a couple of input parameters and a "Connect Button" and is around 300x400px in size. 
Note: I can access, modify and compile these applications.

What I want now is another (QT) application that allows me combine multiple of those applications above into a single window. I'm thinking like an "Add new Device"-button where I can select one of the existing applications and then it's added to the 'container'.

I don't want to have duplicate code, so I don't want to copy the code from all the applications and include it to one large application. All the application logic should remain within those little programs. Then I want to compile them and only provide those compiled files to the Container-Applications.

Is there a design pattern for something like that? Is there a way to have a common base ui-class (implementing QWindow or something like that) to achieve this behavior with QT?

Thanks in advance. Kind regards

Comment: Why do you want to combine existing applications into one, instead of moving the code into a library and use it from one application? Alternative: Create one UI loading plugins for the different devices.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I don't develop those other applications, I only use them. And I often use 4-10 of them simultaneously which gets pretty confusing, so I want to create a cleaner interface. 
But when they release a new version of any of these applications I want to be able to use the new code with as little effort and change possible.